# How can I set an index in a file to be edited with Applescript?

Tags: text, indexing, applescript, editing

As explicitly noted in the title, how can I set a specific index, similar to eof in a text file, so that I can edit text from that point on? If I have a text file of which I want to edit some of the last characters, do I necessarily have to save its contents as a string, edit the string, and write it back to the file?

Answer (score 0):

See the AppleScript dictionary for StandardAdditions, where `write` and `eof` are defined. I believe you're looking to write `starting at` a position in a text file. Note that `write starting at` will overwrite existing text at that position.

[image]